# Create React App Error: Loading Chunk xx failed In Routes with Params

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, create-react-app

I am using **React.lazy** and **Suspense** for code splitting in **Create React App**.

In localhost everything works fine.

After deployment, I am facing this error "***Loading Chunk xx failed***" and console error is "***missing: http://............./static/js/xxxx.chunk.js***". This is only happening in the routes which contains the params, like "*mywebsite.com/event/:id*". Other routes all works fine.

I tried to add Error Boundary and do catch and retry suggested by this article https://medium.com/@botfather/react-loading-chunk-failed-error-88d0bb75b406. I also tried with hard clearing cache for the Chrome. Both ways are still not working.

Any suggestions?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried to build the application and run it. See if you have also in your build same issue as localhost

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the webpack.config. The publicPath needs to be set as '/'

Comment: How did you change the webpack.config?